# Passing parameters to SQLPlus script from Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am trying to pass variables from python script to PL/SQLscript.
But I am getting "SP2-0310: unable to open file" error

Below is the code:

```
def runSqlQuery():
    connectString = '<username>/"<password>"@//MYHOST:1521/TEST'
    var1=input('Enter VAR1: ')
    var2=input('Enter VAR2: ')
    session = ['sqlplus', '-S', connectString,f'@a.sql {var1} {var2}']
    subprocess.call(session)
runSqlQuery()

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 DECLARE
    TYPE usr IS VARRAY(100) OF VARCHAR2(100);
    v_new_rw_user           usr:=usr('&1');
    v_obj_owner             usr:=usr('&2');
 BEGIN
    FOR j IN v_new_rw_user.first..v_new_rw_user.last
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Read Only User : ' || UPPER(v_new_rw_user(j)) ||CHR(10));
        FOR i IN v_obj_owner.first..v_obj_owner.last
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10)||'Database Schema : ' || UPPER(v_obj_owner(i)) ||CHR(10));
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10)||'ERROR CODE : ' || SQLCODE ||CHR(10) || 'ERROR MESSAGE: '|| SQLERRM || CHR(10));
END;
/
EXIT;


Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance
```

Comment: where is a.sql defined?

Comment: a.sql is placed in same location as python script. I able to run the plsql without passing variables from python where variables are provided when plsql script is invoked. But my requirement is to pass variables from python script

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this [tutorial](https://moizmuhammad.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/run-oracle-commands-from-python-via-sql-plus/) the below code works

**TestSQPPlus.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def runSqlQuery():
    connectString = '<username>/"<password>"@//MYHOST:1521/TEST'
    var1=input('Enter VAR1: ')
    var2=input('Enter VAR2: ')
    sqlCommand = f'@a.sql {var1} {var2}'
    print(sqlCommand)
    session =  Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connectString], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    session.stdin.write(sqlCommand.encode())
    return session.communicate()
    
queryResult, errorMessage = runSqlQuery()
print(queryResult)
print(errorMessage)
```

**a.sql**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 DECLARE
    TYPE usr IS VARRAY(100) OF VARCHAR2(100);
    v_new_rw_user           usr:=usr('&1');
    v_obj_owner             usr:=usr('&2');
 BEGIN
    FOR j IN v_new_rw_user.first..v_new_rw_user.last
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Read Only User : ' || UPPER(v_new_rw_user(j)) ||CHR(10));
        FOR i IN v_obj_owner.first..v_obj_owner.last
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10)||'Database Schema : ' || UPPER(v_obj_owner(i)) ||CHR(10));
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10)||'ERROR CODE : ' || SQLCODE ||CHR(10) || 'ERROR MESSAGE: '|| SQLERRM || CHR(10));
END;
/
quit
```

Example of execution (output cut for brevity and formatted)

```
python TestSQPPlus.py
Enter VAR1: x
Enter VAR2: y

Read Only User : X
Database Schema : Y
PL/SQL-Prozedur erfolgreich abgeschlossen.
```

Note - if you want to enter more elements in the `VARRAY` you must *inject* as follows (use at own risc)

```
python TestSQPPlus.py
Enter VAR1: x1','x2
Enter VAR2: y1','y2
@a.sql x1','x2 y1','y2

Read Only User : X1
Database Schema : Y1
Database Schema : Y2
Read Only User : X2
Database Schema : Y1
Database Schema : Y2
PL/SQL-Prozedur erfolgreich abgeschlossen.
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But curious to what is the risk of using above

Comment: @Rajesh, well check unter the title "SQL Injection" you'll find a lot of explanation. You may also accept the answer;)

Comment: I did use the answer :). Thanks

Comment: If you find the answer usefull, you may also [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it;) @Rajesh